# Two subsets and their union have same color

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory, extremal-combinatorics

> Color all nonempty subsets of $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with colors $1,2,\ldots,r$. 
>   Show that, for all large enough $n$, there exist two disjoint nonempty subsets $A,B \subseteq [n]$ such that $A$, $B$, and $A \cup B$ all have the same color.

Answer (score 8):

For two colors, let $n$ be $9$.  There have to be five singletons of the same color.  Let it be red.  Now for this to fail, all pairs of these must be blue. Then all four element sets are red, all three element sets are blue.  Then the set of all five must match one pair of its subsets.  Can you see how to extend this to $r$ colors?

Answer (score 1):

For two colors, let $n$ be $5$. Consider the complete graph on the vertex set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. Color the edges of this $K_6$, giving the edge $uv\ (0\le u\lt v\le5$) the color of the set $\{u+1,u+2,\dots,v\}$. A monochromatic triangle will give you two disjoint nonempty sets $A,B$ and their union $A\cup B$ all of one color. To see that $n=5$ is best possible for $r=2$, color the nonempty subsets of $[4]$ by coloring $1$-sets and $4$-sets red, $2$-sets and $3$-sets blue.

For $r$ colors a similar argument shows that $n=\lfloor r!e\rfloor$ works, but in general this is not best possible.