# Coloring the Powerset of $[n]$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $[n] = \{1,2, \dots, n\}$, and let $\mathcal{P}([n])$ denote its powerset. Given $\mathcal{P}([n])$, we will form a graph $G$ in the following manner: to each element $i \in \mathcal{P}([n])$, associate with it a vertex $v_i$, and add an edge between vertices $v_i, v_j$ if $i \not\subset j$, $j \not\subset i$, and $|i \cap j| \neq \varnothing$. Is there a known result that tells us what $\chi(G)$ is? I've looked around a little bit, but the closest thing I could find was this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577519/k-colorings-of-the-non-empty-subsets-of-n-gives-the-same-color-to-two-disj). It is simple to see:
 $$ \dbinom{n}{\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil} \le \chi(G) $$ since for all elements $i,j \in \mathcal{P}([n])$ with $|i| = |j| = \left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil$, $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent. If an exact result on the coloring is too hard, is there a way to bound $\chi(G)$ from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. Let $G_n$ be the graph with vertex set $V_n=\mathcal P([n])$ and edge set $E_n=\{\{X,Y\}\in\binom{V_n}2:X\setminus Y\ne\emptyset,\ Y\setminus X\ne\emptyset,\ X\cap Y\ne\emptyset\}$.

**Lemma 1.** $\chi(G_n)\le\binom n{\lceil\frac n2\rceil}$.

**Proof.** It's [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem#Width_of_special_partial_orders) that $\mathcal P([n])$ can be decomposed into $\binom n{\lceil\frac n2\rceil}$ chains; chains are independent sets in $G_n$.

**Lemma 2.** $\chi(G_n)\ge\omega(G_n)\ge\binom n{\lceil\frac{n+1}2\rceil}$.

**Proof.** The set of all $\lceil\frac{n+1}2\rceil$-element subsets of $[n]$ is a clique in $G_n$.

**Lemma 3.** If $n=2t\gt2$ then $\chi(G_n)\ge\frac12\binom n{t+1}+\frac12\binom nt=\frac12\binom n{\lceil\frac{n+1}2\rceil}+\frac12\binom n{\lceil\frac n2\rceil}$.

**Proof.** First, we need $\binom n{t+1}$ colors for the $(t+1)$-element sets, which must all be of different colors. Second, if $X$ is a $(t+1)$-element set, then (since $t\gt1$) at most one $t$-element set can have the same color as $X$. Therefore, we need additional colors for the remaining $\binom nt-\binom n{t+1}$ $t$-element sets. Since we can't have more than two (complementary) $t$-element sets of the same color, it follows that
$$\chi(G_n)\ge\binom n{t+1}+\frac{\binom nt-\binom n{t+1}}2=\frac12\binom n{t+1}+\frac12\binom nt.$$

**Theorem.** $\frac12\binom n{\lceil\frac{n+1}2\rceil}+\frac12\binom n{\lceil\frac  n2\rceil}\le\chi(G_n)\le\binom n{\lceil\frac n2\rceil}$ for $n\ne2$.

**Proof.** The upper bound is Lemma 1. The lower bound is Lemma 2 for odd $n$ and Lemma 3 for even $n$ except $n=0$ which can be checked separately.

**Corollary.** If $n$ is odd then $\chi(G_n)=\binom n{\lceil\frac n2\rceil}$.

**Proof.** $\lceil\frac{n+1}2\rceil=\lceil\frac n2\rceil$ if $n$ is odd.

**Remark 1.** $\chi(G_4)=5$.

**Proof.** $\chi(G_4)\ge5$ by Lemma 3. To show $\chi(G_4)\le5$ we only need to color the non-isolated vertices of $G_4$, i.e., the sets of size $2$ or $3$.

Color 1: $\{1,2,3\},\ \{1,3\}$
Color 2: $\{1,2,4\},\ \{2,4\}$
Color 3: $\{1,3,4\},\ \{1,4\}$
Color 4: $\{2,3,4\},\ \{2,3\}$
Color 5: $\{1,2\},\ \{3,4\}$

**Remark 2.** $18\le\chi(G_6)\le20$; what is the actual value?

Comment: +1 a very nice approach!  First, this may already answer the OP question, since the ratio between the bounds $\to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.  Second, if I understand you correctly, then the lower bound is tight if we can find a way to assign existing colors to ${n \choose t+1}$ of the ${n \choose t}$ size-$t$ subsets in a way that the _unassigned_ size-$t$ subsets come in pairs, right?  This reduces everything to a bipartite matching problem.

Comment: @bof This is an excellent answer! The fact about chains and Lemma 3 are particularly exciting. I'm going to try and calculate $\chi(G_{2n})$ for several values of small $n$; perhaps that can give a hint as to where the bound lies. I'll post an update with those values when I get them.

Comment: @Quotable Brute-forcing by hand I get $\chi(G_6)=18$, so I'm going to **guess** that $$\chi(G_n)=\left\lceil\frac12\binom n{\lceil\frac{n+1}2\rceil}+\frac12\binom n{\lceil\frac n2\rceil}\right\rceil$$ for all $n\ne2$, but I'm not going to work on this any more.

Comment: @bof I do have one final question regarding the above: I was reading through the link regarding Lemma 1. Why is it that we have 
$$\chi(G_n) \le \binom{n}{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil} \ \ \ \ \text{   instead of    } \ \ \ \  \chi(G_n) \le \binom{n}{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}$$
Based on my understanding of the article (and related pages), the size of the largest antichain is the width of a partially ordered set, and by Dilworth's theorem this is the min number of chains the set can be partitioned into, so shouldn't we have the latter bound from above here?

Comment: They are the same. If $n=2k$ they are both $\binom{2k}k$, the middle binomial coefficient. If $n=2k+1$ one is $\binom{2k+1}k$ and the other is $\binom{2k+1}{k+1}$, the two middle binomial coefficients, which are equal. I chose the ceiling for esthetic reasons, to go with the ceiling in your lower bound.

Comment: @antkam It's a matching problem but it's not exactly bipartite, is it? For $n=2k$ we want a maximum matching in the graph which has edges joining each element of $\binom{[n]}{k+1}$ to each of its subsets in $\binom{[n]}k$, but also edges joining each element of $\binom{[n]}k$ to its complement.

Comment: @bof Good point.  If we model complement-ness (complementarity?) as an edge (your idea above) then the graph is not bipartite, whereas if we don't (my original half-formed idea) then it's unclear how to write the optimality criterion.  Anyway your idea makes this polynomial time solvable.  Awesome!